# not getting any output on some grep command in WSL

Tags: grep, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So i just started to learn about grep and i tried to use it on WSL Ubuntu. but some grep commands give no output like the line - grep '123$' sampledata.txt - doesn't provide any output. when i tried this on my Azure vm it works fine. is anyone else facing this issue and is there someway to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the `123` is immediately followed with `\n` and not `\r\n`? Try `grep -P '123\r?$' sampledata.txt`

Comment: i tried the command with \r did not work. it gives a blank output.
update: i just ran the script with vs code it just gave me the output.

Comment: Did you use `-P`? What is `vs code`?

Comment: whenever i tried to run it on windows terminal it doesn't work. maybe a bug in windows terminal? visual studio code with wsl

Comment: In Windows terminal? What do you mean? CMD? Run that in Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: windows terminal supports wsl

Comment: Ok, so `grep '123$' < <(sed 's/\r//g' sampledata.txt)` works and just because of the CRLF endings.

Comment: @hamad3xk I think I get what you are saying, but let me be sure.  When you run the `grep` from within your WSL session running in Windows Terminal, it doesn't output anything.  But when you run the same command in WSL (assuming the same distribution) running as the shell in Visual Studio Code, against the same file, it *does* work, right?  I'd recommend editing the question to include some of these new findings.  If I'm understanding you correctly, then it doesn't seem to be a line-ending problem, because that should, I would think, show up in WSL under VSCode as well.

Comment: Can you provide your file?  Also, what about something simple (and built-in) like `grep 'bash$' /etc/passwd`?

Comment: Also just noticed that you posted this on Stack Overflow.  Please note that questions here should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Unix & Linux Stack](https://unix.stackexechange.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with that site's rules for posting as well.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds noted. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the CR symbols that come at the end of lines first:

```sh
grep '123$' < <(sed 's/\r$//g' sampledata.txt)
```

In Windows, lines have CRLF endings, in Linux, there are LF endings.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the encoding of file and feed the output to grep command

iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 sampledata.txt |  grep '123$' sampledata.txt

This works for me when the files are created in Windows.

PS: I got the answer from here Credit where it Deserves

http://notesofaprogrammer.blogspot.com/2020/05/grep-does-not-work-on-wsl.html

Comment: I find exactly the same page as you mentioned, and with the "iconv", I can run the grep successfully as expected.